# jQuery DataTables initial data is printed out while table is modified

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have created a function wherein I edit every value in my datatable.
here is my code:

```
$('#xin_table2').on('click', 'td', function () {
 $(this).children('span').addClass("none");
 $(this).children('input').removeClass("none");     
 $(this).children('input').focus();

 $(this).children('input').on('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
         $(this).addClass("none");
         $(this).siblings('span').text($(this).val());
         $(this).siblings('span').removeClass("none");       

        $.ajax({
           url: site_url+"payroll/edit_data_payroll/",
           type: 'POST',
           data: {'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>':'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>',id: $(this).attr("data-id"), column:$(this).attr("data-column"), data:$(this).val()},
           error: function() {
              toastr.error('Something is wrong');
           },
           success: function(data) {
            toastr.success(data);
           }
        });    
    }   
    });

  $(this).children('input').blur(function(){
     $(this).addClass("none");
    $(this).val($(this).siblings('span').text());
     $(this).siblings('span').removeClass("none");
 });

});
```

When you click a `td` element, the span will hide and the input field will show and you can save the new data by pressing the enter button. The span will also change its value. This code works fine.

The problem is, when I print the datatable it shows the older value even though the value of the span changed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem. 
I added this code inside the success function of my ajax:

```
 $('#xin_table2').dataTable().api().ajax.reload(function(){ }, true);
```